# R Programming - Rolling average with grouping

Tags: r

I am working on doing a rolling average of a column by grouping another column.  The groups are "PlayerName", the rolling average is by "FDP".  Here is the test data I am using:

```
PlayerName <- c("Player1", "Player1", "Player1", "Player1", "Player2", "Player2", "Player2", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3")

Date <- c("2016-11-02", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-07", "2016-11-10", "2016-11-03", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-11", "2016-11-02", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-07", "2016-11-10", "2016-11-13", "2016-11-17")

FDP <- c(13, 12, 8, 20, 10, 11, 12, 35, 46, 24, 33, 40, 40)

DT <- data.table(PlayerName, Date, FDP)
```

I want to add a 4th column "RollAvg" that is the 3 Date rolling average.  The result would look something like:

```
    PlayerName       Date FDP  RollAvg
 1:    Player1 2016-11-02  13    NA
 2:    Player1 2016-11-04  12    NA
 3:    Player1 2016-11-07   8    11
 4:    Player1 2016-11-10  20    13.3
 5:    Player2 2016-11-03  10    NA
 6:    Player2 2016-11-04  11    NA
 7:    Player2 2016-11-11  12    11
 8:    Player3 2016-11-02  35    NA
 9:    Player3 2016-11-04  46    NA
10:    Player3 2016-11-07  24    35
11:    Player3 2016-11-10  33    34.3
12:    Player3 2016-11-13  40    32.3
13:    Player3 2016-11-17  40    37.6
```

It doesn't matter to me if the RollAvg column has NA's or if they are omitted.

I have tried a bunch of different ways to do this, and I can't get anything to work.  I know there are other similar posts, but I couldn't get the structures of what they were doing to work.  I feel like there is some simple one line way to do this with sapply and rollmean, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Previously answered by [This SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787526/grouped-rolling-average-by-date)

Comment: I tried using that and I could not get it to work.  I am a newbie, so maybe it was just beyond me.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As several other SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644494/applying-rolling-mean-by-group-in-r) suggest, you can make use of the `zoo` package's `rollapply()` function to solve this problem:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

PlayerName <- c("Player1", "Player1", "Player1", "Player1", "Player2", "Player2", "Player2", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3", "Player3")

Date <- c("2016-11-02", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-07", "2016-11-10", "2016-11-03", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-11", "2016-11-02", "2016-11-04", "2016-11-07", "2016-11-10", "2016-11-13", "2016-11-17")

FDP <- c(13, 12, 8, 20, 10, 11, 12, 35, 46, 24, 33, 40, 40)

data.frame(PlayerName, Date, FDP) %>% 
        mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
        arrange(PlayerName,Date) %>% 
        group_by(PlayerName) %>%
        mutate(RollAvg = zoo::rollapply(FDP,3,mean,by = 1,align = "right",fill = NA))
```

which returns:

```
Source: local data frame [13 x 4]
Groups: PlayerName [3]

   PlayerName       Date   FDP  RollAvg
       <fctr>     <date> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     Player1 2016-11-02    13       NA
2     Player1 2016-11-04    12       NA
3     Player1 2016-11-07     8 11.00000
4     Player1 2016-11-10    20 13.33333
5     Player2 2016-11-03    10       NA
6     Player2 2016-11-04    11       NA
7     Player2 2016-11-11    12 11.00000
8     Player3 2016-11-02    35       NA
9     Player3 2016-11-04    46       NA
10    Player3 2016-11-07    24 35.00000
11    Player3 2016-11-10    33 34.33333
12    Player3 2016-11-13    40 32.33333
13    Player3 2016-11-17    40 37.66667
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I had actually found that thread and couldn't get it to work.  After I ran your code and it didn't work either I found I needed to update R, and then it worked perfectly.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Also note `rollmeanr` .